# How to add the sale of one day in only one row and same date in one column in php?

Tags: php, arrays

i have a array result like the below. it show every payment on each day but i want to add the all the payment in of a day in only one row and the date in one col how can i do that ? thanks

Array `( [cols] => 2017-09-10 [rows] => 1311.45 ) [1] => Array ( [cols] => 2017-09-10 [rows] => 1311.45 ) [2] => Array ( [cols] => 2017-09-10 [rows] => 175000.00 )`

my code look like this

```
 foreach($Todaysales as $d)

 {

     $data[] = ['cols' => date("Y-m-d", strtotime($d['sale_time'])),'rows' => $d['payment_amount']];

 }
```

My desired output is

```
[[cols]=> 2017-09-10 [rows]=> sum(2017-09-10's sales)]
```

## edited code

```
 $data=Array
(
    [2017-09-10] => 178934.35
    [2017-09-09] => 700000
    [2017-09-07] => 194432.25
    [2017-09-06] => 183252.9
    [2017-09-03] => 1311.45
    [2017-09-02] => 1186.55
    [2017-08-30] => 204660.3
    [2017-08-29] => 290486.45
    [2017-08-28] => 2400
    [2017-08-27] => 600.00
    [2017-08-26] => 840.00
    [2017-08-16] => 600.00
)
```

to this format after json encoding

```
[{"cols":"2017-09-02 ","rows":"1186.55"},{"cols":"2017-09-03","rows":"1311.45"}
```

Comment: show your desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code you will get date as key and sum of sales amount as value

```
foreach($Todaysales as $d)

 {

     if(isset($data[$d['sale_time']]))
         $data[$d['sale_time']] += $d['payment_amount'];
     else
         $data[$d['sale_time']] = $d['payment_amount'];

 }
 print_r($data);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/6TgNO)

**EDIT**
If you want same output as you specified. You can try following

```
$data = array();
foreach($Todaysales as $d)
{
     $match_key =false;
     $match_key = array_search($d['sale_time'],array_column($data, "cols"));

     if($match_key > 0 || $match_key === 0)
        $data[$match_key]["rows"] = $data[$match_key]["rows"] + $d['payment_amount'];
     else
         $data[] = array("cols"=>$d['sale_time'],"rows"=>$d['payment_amount']);

}
print_r($data);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/rmlVh)

**EDIT** as per your comment you need it for google chart try below answer:

```
foreach($Todaysales as $d)

 {

     if(isset($data[$d['sale_time']]))
         $data[$d['sale_time']] += $d['payment_amount'];
     else
         $data[$d['sale_time']] = $d['payment_amount'];

 }

 $new_data["cols"] ="'".implode("','",array_keys($data))."'";
 $new_data["rows"] =implode(",",array_values($data));
 print_r($new_data);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/DmKsa)

Comment: i got output like

Comment: See edited answer @MirthfulNahid if you want same out put like `rows` and `cols`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array ()  ...  i dont want these  .....i want like [[cols]=> date , [row] => amount ]

Comment: what if there is multiple dates?

Comment: yes there are multiple dates but i want it like these so that i can plot the data by google chart

Comment: now i get  array( [cols] => all the dates ............in one col  , [rows]=> all the values in one rows...........

Comment: So what you want? Show your desired output when there is multiple dates

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr=[
    Array ( 'cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 1311.45 ), 
    Array ( 'cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 1311.45 ),
    Array ( 'cols'=> '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 175000.00 )
];
$r['cols']=$arr[0]['cols'];
$r['rows']=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($arr);++$i){
    $r['rows']+=$arr[$i]['rows'];
}
print_r($r);
```

Answer (score 1):

To modify the previous given array you can do so:

```
$Todaysales = [
     ['cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 1311.45],
     ['cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 1311.45],
     ['cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 175000.00]
];

foreach($Todaysales as $d)
 {
     $data[$d['cols']][] = $d['rows'];
 }

print_r($data);
```

will return:

```
Array
(
    [2017-09-10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1311.45
            [1] => 1311.45
            [2] => 175000
        )

)
```

But it seems that you also generate the first array yourself, if so you should give us the code that generates $Todaysales if to change it at the origin.

**[EDIT] after question edit**

```
$Todaysales = [
     ['cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 1311.45],
     ['cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 1311.45],
     ['cols' => '2017-09-10', 'rows' => 175000.00]
];

$today_sales = ['cols' => date('Y-m-d'), 'rows' => 0];

foreach($Todaysales as $d)
 {
    $today_sales['rows'] += $d['rows'];
 }
print_r($today_sales);
```

returns

```
Array
(
    [cols] => 2017-09-10
    [rows] => 177622.9
)
```